# Including PHP classes not found further down page

Tags: php, class, facebook-graph-api, php-include

I have had a look around but still can't find out why my Class isn't been found in my page.

I am including the new Facebook v4 API in my Wordpress site - above the header:

```
//top of site   
include('pageInc/FacebookHeader.php'); 
get_header();  
include('pageInc/innerHeader.php');
```

But then inside innerHeader.php I am calling the classes defined in FacebookHeader.php:

```
$fbsession = new FacebookSession( $fbsession->getToken() );
$request = new FacebookRequest( $fbsession, 'GET', '/me' );
```

And its showing an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'FacebookSession' not found in ...innerHeader.php on line 21
```

If I call the class in the FacebookHeader page it works fine, but just doesn't work inside the actual site. Surely you can just call the class anywhere in the page once it's been included?

The very top of the site in FacebookHeader i am calling the class like:

```
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does the class have namespaces?

Comment: Yes they do - namespace Facebook;

Comment: You should prepend the namespace when you call the class.

Comment: Ok I put it in middle of the php page and it said that it had to be the first line in the script, so I put it at the top of the PHP page (still under the main header) and now it works. So namespace declarations have to be at the top of the actual .php page? Is this right?

Comment: Yes, the namespace is the first thing you declare when you're writing a class.

Comment: Yes but then I have to include it int eh middle of the page if I want to call that class further down the site. What if I wish to use 2 classes in the same php file? Do I include the 2 namepsaces?

Comment: No that doesn't matter, you can include it wherever you want. As long as it's before you call the class.